# Callouts exception and attempt to dereference a null object

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, unit-test

I am writing test class that includes callouts and method that take value from a object. And record of this Object already inserted in db. And this method is called on click of a button.

The problem I am facing is that `getStoredValueMethod()` has to take value from a object. Value of this object already stored in DB.

Now In test class ,when I am assigning value to this method and inserted object its showing the below error:

> You have uncommitted work pending'. Please commit or rollback before
>   calling out.

And if I am not inserting any value . I am getting error:

> Attempt to de-reference a null object.

How can I fix this issue?

```
@auraenabled 
public void getAllinfo(){ 
public void getCalloutsMethods(){} 
public void getStoredValueMethod(){}
public void insertData(){}
}
@auraenabled 
public void getStoredValueMethod(){
 ABC__c abcObj;
           if(abcObj != null)
           {
           try{
                    abcObj = [SELECT id,Name__c from ABC__c where Name__c = 'xyz' LIMIT 1];
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                     abcObj = [SELECT id,Name rom ABC__c where Name__c = 'abc' LIMIT 1];
                }
}
```

Comment: Please post your whole code. There is no callout on the piece you posted. Also, you didn't post your test.

Comment: Object should be initialized. `ABC__c abcObj;` -> `ABC__c abcObj - new ABC__c;` Also it is a poor use of try catch, do a query inside a list.

Comment: Change the order of the callout if its not having any functioanl relation inbetween . 1 ) public void getStoredValueMethod(){} ;  2) public void getCalloutsMethods(){}

Comment: I have written mock class for callouts. I have used rest api for httpcallouts.@IsTest global class AbcControllerTest{
@IsTest 
 global static void testMethod()  {
    Test.startTest(); 
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Mock());  
      // New object
    Aaabc__c AaabcObj = new Aaabc__c();
  //  insert AaabcObj;   
    AbcController.getAllinfo();    
Test.stopTest();}}    now i will get error 'Attempt to de-reference a null object'. but if I uncommented insert statement.. i will get 'You have uncommitted work pending'. Please commit or rollback before calling out.'

Comment: @Martin.I have posted test class above.@rahul.I have tried ,but getting same error..

Comment: @bharath..if I change order , still i will get error..because I am inserting data that I get from callout methods in insertData(). So I did not get any solution till now.

Comment: Call outs cannot be done after dml. Setmock must be within start and stop. Dml must be before start. You will need to provide the relevant code before any specific answers can be given

Comment: @Eric ..this is the only problem I am getting .. Can not insert record before callouts. I have provided all the code. and also I have tried to insert before start test.. I does'nt help..

Comment: If that is all the code then you are on your own here. All you have provided is a query

Comment: Thanks to all ..But there was issue becaouse of if(abcObj != null)..I have removed this condition and error has removed..